# valgrind printf() error with thread program in c

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

So i wrote this program in c and the idea was that it reads from 3 files and shows ther content. It works fine but I get an error when I run it with valgrind.
This is the program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <pthread.h>


  struct structFile{
  int numFile;
  char* fileName;
 };

 void* fileThread(void* arg){
 struct structFile* threadStruct = (struct structFile*) arg;
 FILE *file = fopen(threadStruct->fileName, "r");`
 //char* charS = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);`
 char *charS = malloc(10 + 1);
 int sizeC = fread(charS, 1, 10, file);
 charS[sizeC] = '\0';
 while (sizeC < 10){
     charS[sizeC] = ' ';
     sizeC++; 
 }//while
 fclose(file);
 printf("%d. nit: %s\n", threadStruct->numFile, charS);
 return charS;

}//fileThread

int main(int argc, char **argv){
 pthread_t id[3]; 
 char* word[3];
 struct structFile* mainStruct = (struct structFile*) malloc (sizeof(struct structFile)*3);
 for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     mainStruct[i].numFile = i;
     mainStruct[i].fileName = (char*)argv[i+1];
     pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, fileThread, mainStruct+i);
 }//for

 for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     pthread_join(id[i], (void**) &word[i]);
 }//for
 printf("Sporocilo-> %s %s %s\n", word[0], word[1], word[2]);
 free(mainStruct);
 free(word[0]); 
 free(word[1]);
 free(word[2]);

 return 0;
 }//main
```

[image: And this is the error I get:]
I really have no idea what could be wrong hear, some times it shows 7 errors sometimes 4. I started with c programming about 1 month ago so it could be just a simple answer so thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Where do you check to see if your `fopen()` succeeds?

Comment: Maybe you should check the return value of  `malloc`. `malloc` will return `NULL` on error, this may cause a SIGSEGV in fread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `charS` doesn't have space for null byte (since you want to print as string with `%s`).

Allocate one extra byte and properly null terminate it.

```
char *charS = malloc(10 + 1); // sizeof(char) can be omitted as it's always 1
int sizeC = fread(charS, 1, 10, file);
charS[sizeC] = '\0';

...
```

You should also add error checking for `fopen`, `malloc`, `pthread_create`, etc.

Comment: Can you update the question with your modified code (with this change)?

Comment: @Novice When I recompile it and run under valgrind, it doesn't show any issues. Did you recompile and rerun under valgrind?

Answer (score 0):

fread read 10 characters so you need to allocate 11 chars for the '\0'.
Malloc like this :

```
         char* charS = malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);`
```